# How to enable desktop effects on Ubuntu 10.04 after upgrade from Ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: 10.04, compiz, intel

I upgraded my Ubuntu 8.04 to Ubuntu 10.04 and when i try to enable desktop effects it says:    **Desktop effects could not be enabled**. The output of `lspci | grep VGA` is :

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation
>   82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device (rev 03)

Hardware drivers says there is no propriority hardware driver. I installed nVidia driver but I think my is an Intel graphics device.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Due to issues with GPU lockups when running OpenGL applications on i845 devices Ubuntu 10.04 (and 10.10 so far) has DRI completely disabled for this class of devices. Compiz (desktop effects) is failing to run due to a lack of hardware acceleration. You can follow [bug 541492](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/541492) on Launchpad to check for updates to this situation.

Comment: Is it that it is not solvable?

Answer (score 0):

To start with you should remove the nvidia drivers as they will be useless then I would check for broken packages you can do both of these from synaptic package manager.[image: synaptic package manager looking at broken packages filter] as you can see I don't have any at the moment. Next I would check which version of Compiz you have installed this post from the Compiz forums is probably what is happening in your case basicaly the packages are still for 8.04 and havent been updated to 10.04 the solution was to check for any 8.04 sources in your sources list and remove then purge compiz and reinstall from the correct sources.

Hope this helps.

Please tell us how you get on.

Comment: Should I remove nvidia drivers installed? Wont it effect the X system? I already purged Compiz and reinstalled it again from the software center but no effect.